# Solar system: 40 A DC AND fuses. What is the difference between Audio and Solar version of this fuse?

Tags: fuses, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

So, I've purchased some 40A ANL fuses and holders for my solar controllers and I'm hooking them up tonight after the sun goes down.  Due to a comment from a neighbor, I went back and reviewed my purchases (from Amazon) and discovered that I did not notice the part about the fuseblock and fuse being for audio purposes.  The solar controllers (Victron) have a max output of 30A (why they want a 40A fuse, I don't understand).  These fuses are in between the Lithium battery bus (14.4V charging) and the wires that run to the solar controllers.

What is different about this application from audio other than this will be continuous high current for 6 hours a day vs intermittent power (although based on some of the people around here, the volume seems more constant that variable).

I have the same question about 100A DC fuse blocks and holders.  They are protecting the wires between the battery bus and a Victron MPPT that has a max output of 85A.  There are the same make and model that come with 350A fuses so this seems like it should work, but the blue sea systems fuses are $20 each and these are $12 for 2 including the holders.

The current being carried is between the controller and the batteries, not the panels and the controller

Comment: Although this fuse is on the low voltage side of things, in a Solar system there's the potential for fairly high voltage continuous current. A fuse to break 12 V might not stay open when faced with 100 V...  Also I would use name brand components with UL ratings for anything high current like this, installed in or on a house.

Comment: If this is a home installation, do you have the necessary info and permits to legally install it yourself?

Comment: Does no one know if there is a difference in those types of fuses?  I'm in Mexico, there is no permit to pull.

Comment: Link to datasheets for the different fuses so we can compare them. "40A fuse from Amazon" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: If I had datasheets, I wouldn't have this question.  Good news, 3 days in and everything is working just fine.  Maybe the question isn't clear:  "What is the difference between an Audio and a Solar version of this (40A) fuse?"